# How to get starting and stoping time of an application?

Tags: android

I am new to android.

I am implementing one application.

Related to my app

I want to get starting and stoping time of each application.

If any one know the solution please help me,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "of each application" as in "all other applications on the phone"?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not stopping your activity by using finish()  method.. then i think it is difficult to know when the activity is closed exactly.. because **onDestroy** is the method called when the activity is finished (someone called finish() on it, or because the system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space... but there are situations where the system will simply kill the activity's hosting process without calling this method (or any others) in it...[See about onDestroy method here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

you can get starting time onStart() function and activity end time in onStop() just define given code in the functions.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    Date StartTime = c.getTime();
    Log.i("Start Time", String.valueOf(StartTime));
```

Answer (score 0):

First take a shared pref.

As you know your application when it first launches in that component(activity,service) go to oncreate() and create share pref and save the current system time.

and finally u know where is last activity or service in that ondestroy(). bring the values which u stored in shared pref.

Now u minus current system - this stored start time. you will get the time total time spent in you app. if you want u can save this to shared pref.